# Regexp for "IF textTrue ELSE textFalse"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two strings:

```
"~if~ text_if_true ~end~"
"~if~ text_if_true ~else~ text_if_false ~end~"
```

All I want is a regexp with give following output:

for 1. =>

```
group 1 = text_if_true
```

for 2. =>

```
group 1 = text_if_true, group 2 = text_if_false
```

I tried:

```
~if~(.*?)(?:~else~)(.*?)~end~
```

Work fine on II but not on I because the ~else~ is needed

if I use

```
~if~(.*?)(?:~else~)?(.*?)~end~
```

With a `?` behind `(?:~else~)` (for 0 or 1 matches) the `text_if_true` and the `text_if_false` is in the first group.

Is there a easy way to solve the problem?

```js
const regex = /~if~(.*?)(?:~else~)(.*?)~end~/gm;
const regex2 = /~if~(.*?)(?:~else~)?(.*?)~end~/gm;

const str = `~if~ text_if_true ~else~ text_if_false ~end~
~if~ text_if_true ~end~`;
let m;


console.log('without ? quantifier')
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}

console.log('with ? quantifier')
while ((m = regex2.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making just the word `~else~` optional, you should make the whole of `~else~ (.*?)` optional (I have also added some spaces so that the groups don't have leading or trailing spaces):

```
if~ (.*?)(?: ~else~ (.*?))? ~end
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SfqnWj/1)

Comment: Thank you! :) Sometimes you do not see the forest for the trees!

Answer (score 1):

You could make the part `~else~ text_if_false` optional like the example below.

```js
var input = ["~if~ text_if_true ~end~",
"~if~ text_if_true ~else~ text_if_false ~end~"];

var re = /~if~ (.*?)(?: ~else~ (.*?))? ~end~/
for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++)
   console.log(input[i].match(re));
```